# DEBUG: Routing failed, re-queued. Kannel

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, modem, sms-gateway, kannel

Hi I am trying to setup Kannel 1.4.3 for sending and receiving SMS. But I'm getting Routing Failed error 
ERROR: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: Couldn't connect (retrying in 10 seconds).

Message in the browser:

3: Queued for later delivery

Details:

Modem - Huawei e220
Sim - AT&T
OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the following smskannel.conf:

```
#---------------------------------------------
# CORE
#

group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
#status-password = foo
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
#unified-prefix = "+358,00358,0;+,00"

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSC CONNECTIONS
#

group = smsc
smsc = at
smsc-id = Huawei-E220-00
port = 10000
modemtype = huawei_e220_00
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
sms-center = +13123149810
my-number = +1xxxxxxxxxx
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
sim-buffering = true
keepalive = 5

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSBOX SETUP
#

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013

#---------------------------------------------
# SEND-SMS USERS
#

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar

#---------------------------------------------
# SERVICES

group = sms-service
keyword = nop
text = "You asked nothing and I did it!"

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"

group = sms-service
keyword = complex
catch-all = yes
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
max-messages = 3
concatenation = true
get-url = "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&to=+16782304782&text=Hello World"

#---------------------------------------------
# MODEMS
#
group = modems
id = huawei_e220_00
name = "Huawei E220"
detect-string = "huawei"
init-string = "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
message-storage = "SM"
need-sleep = true
speed = 460800`
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and is off-topic here. It's most likely better suited for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.